# $A_{n\times n}$ be a complex matrix with $A^2 = -I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A_{n\times n}$  be a complex matrix with $A^2 = -I$.

I want to prove that $A^3 = A^{-1}$, and disprove that $I - A = A^{-1}$.

I do not know if the matrix is invertible, else, this will simplify the rest of the work. Suppose that its not invertible, and suppose that i cant deduce from $A^2 + I = 0$ that $A$ is in polynomial vector space, particularly for $x^2 + 1$ dimension. How can I prove the first part?

For the second part:

$(1)\quad I - A = A^{-1} / \cdot A$

$(2)\quad A^{-1} - A^2 = I /$ substitute the given argument

$(3)\quad A^{-1} + I = I \quad \leftrightarrow \quad A^{-1} = 0$

Which is sort of "reductio ad absurdum" because the zero matrix is not invertible. Is this a correct proof?

Any advice and help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: $A^2=-I$ means $A=-A^{-1}$, so that $A^3=AA^2=-A=A^{-1}$.

Comment: A is invertible since $det(A)^2≠0$

Comment: Using that A.(-A) = (-A).A = Id, we know that A is invertible with inverse equal to -A.

Comment: Edited a typo. @DietrichBurde is this holds for every matrix, even the complex one?

Comment: $A^2 = -I$ tells you $A$ is invertible since  $-A$ is its inverse.

Comment: You write at the beginning that $A^2 = -I$, which implies that $A \cdot -A = I$. Therefore, the right (and left) inverse of $A$ is $-A$.

Comment: Squaring what you have gives $A^4=I$. Therefore $(A^3)A=I=A(A^3)$ and you are done.

Comment: There are many answers in comments here. [Answering in Comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments) has been an issue for a long time. If the question is worth answering, please write an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize the comments, we have the following short answer.

1. $A^2=-I$ implies that $A$ is invertible with $A=-A^{-1}$ and $A^4=I$. Hence we may multiply $A^4=I$ by $A^{-1}$ on both sides to obtain $A^3=A^{-1}=-A$.
2. You can disprove $I-A=A^{-1}$ by choosing
   $$
   A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \cr 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
   $$
   Then $A^2=-I$, but $A^{-1}=-A\neq I-A$. For a $1\times 1$-matrix there is no real matrix $A$ with $A^2=-I$. Over the complex numbers, $A=(i)$ satisfies $A^2=-I$ and $I-A\neq A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

if $A^2=-I$, then $A^2+I=0$. By multyplying on both sides by $A$,we find $A^3+A=0\iff A^3=-A$.

Since $A^2=-I$ and $A$ is invertible because $\det(A^2)=\det(A)^2\neq0\implies \det(A)\neq 0$, we can multiply by the inverse *(as it exists)* on both sides and find $A=-A^{-1}\implies -A=A^{-1}$.
So finally:
$$A^3=-A=A^{-1}$$

Thus $A^3=A^{-1}$.

For the second part, since $-A=A^{-1}$ and $I\neq 0$, $I-A\neq A^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

If $A^2=-I$, then $A^4=I$, which directly implies that $A(A^3)=(A^3)A=I$; hence $A^3=A^{-1}$.

For the second part, $I-A \ne A^{-1}$ because
$$
      A(I-A)=(I-A)A= A-A^2 = A+I \ne I.
$$